# LuaLaTeX packages for bold math symbols

Tags: luatex, preamble

I am writing a document, and this is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages dealing with fonts
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

% Packages dealing with page layout, items and placements
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, dashed=false sorting=nyt, giveninits=true, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=10, uniquelist=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Packages dealing with tables
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

% Packages dealing with figures
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I need the following math functions: `\mathscr`, `\mathcal`, `\boldsymbol` along with other standard math symbols and accents (like `\hat`, `\widetilde`, etc.). However, using the preamble above, I cannot get bold symbols. What am I missing?

Comment: you can get all those via unicode-math, but to use the main math font use `\symbf`, `\symcal` etc

Comment: `unicode-math` does not have `eqref`. What is the equivalent replacement? Thanks!

Comment: `\eqref` is from `amsmath` which `unicode-math` doesn't replace at all, just load both packages (`amsmath` first)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get all those via `unicode-math`, but to use the main math font use `\symbf`, `\symcal` etc. To use `amsmath` constructs such as `\eqref` just load `amsmath` before `unicode-math`.